How can I configure Pytest such that my tests run in a different working directory
I have python project like this:
C:.
├───src
│   │   config.json
│   │   main.py
└───tests

Where every test in tests contains some code that reads config.json which is stored in src.
I would like my tests to run from the perspective of main.py, i.e. I want my working directory for all of my tests to be src. How can I configure vscode (using pyproject.toml, settings.json, or some other config) such that the working directory of my tests is src? In Pycharm I can change change pytest configuration such that the working directory will be src.
I have tried in settings.json to set

"python.testing.cwd": "./src"

but this has issues with discoverability of my tests after restarting vscode.
How can I change pytest's working directory? Is the same question, but nobody answered that one.

If you change it to "python.testing.cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/src", will it work?

According to the Pytest documentation, you can set a PYTHONPATH in the pytest.ini file.
# pytest.ini inside the tests folder
[pytest]
pythonpath = ../src


According to the documentation, every directory that you add to pythonpath gets added to sys.path, which I already use in order for my tests to import modules from src. However, this doesn't change the working directory of my tests.
